# How do I boot into my new Arch dual boot?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I’m a fairly new Linux user, who’s had a dual booted machine for a while. I decided to give Arch Linux a shot, so I followed the install guide on the wiki. At the moment, my machine has one SSD which is partitioned. It has some recovery stuff which is unimportant, a 100mb Fat32 Windows Boot partition, the actual windows partition, and the partition where I’m installing arch.  I actually managed to install arch on the partition, and it works just fine. My issue is now trying to get my computer to boot into arch.

My laptop at the moment is UEFI. The way I previously booted into Linux (I tried ubuntu and manjaro in the past) was to spam my f12 key to get into Windows boot manager and then I could select the os I wanted to boot into, and I had windows as the first entry for it to just boot into it automatically if I never pressed anything. However, I can’t get arch to show up as an entry in the list. When I try adding stuff with efibootmgr it doesn’t work, and frankly I’m just lost on how I would even go about adding it. With most graphical installs all you have to do is to select your root partition and then select your boot partition [the windows efi one, making sure not to format it so it just adds it to what’s already there], and then the os shows up in the menu for me.

I’m aware that I can just install grub and have my system boot that way, but I’d rather stick with the windows boot because I don’t want to have to worry about windows updates messing with my bootloader.

I’m just a bit lost on what to do, and I would greatly appreciate a step in the right direction

Edit: I am able to “boot” into arch by plugging in the usb that I had the iso loaded onto, and then mounting it to the correct partition, and then running arch-chroot. So I can still work inside the Linux system just fine, but I’d like to be able to boot into it normally.

Comment: I think the easiest route is going to be to use GRUB. If Windows bricks it, just re-run `grub-install` from your *master* distro (only let one distro install grub or it'll switch themes etc)

Comment: Fo Arch Linux I always recommend **not** to use GRUB, and use systemd-boot instead. With UEFI you only need a chooser application, and that's exactly what systemd-boot is. GRUB has grown into a unnecessary complicated monster.

Comment: Are you using the same efi partition for Windows and Linux? That would be the normal way and should work with `systemd-boot` too. But if you have separate one (I prefer this, because then it's hard for Windows to cause problems with the Linux side of things - but complicates things a bit) then `systemd-boot` won't work. The only loader that worked for me in this configuration was `rEFInd` (but grub should too).